# On click function that sends data with AJAX to a php file for it to be saved in the database only works once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onclick

I am trying to create a remove button in an "edit form" code I've been working in. The button **1)** gets the ID of the its div parent and then **2)** gets the value of the inputs inside of named parent in order to **3)** send them with an AJAX call to a PHP file that works on **4)** inserting that information inside a table in the database.

At first, the code works as it should. It inserts the information into the database and retrieves it while modifying an existing div. But it only works once. When other button with the same class  (and therefore the same function) is clicked, the `success:function` works just fine and shows the corresponding data, but does not save the data into the database as the previous button did. If I reload the page, again, any button works, but the data it's being saved just once.

I've tried using `cache: false`, but when I place it into my AJAX call, the buttons stop working completely.

```
$(document).on('click','.removeQe',function(e) {
    var reId = $(this).attr('id');
    var box = $('#'+reId+'').parent().parent().attr('id');
    var input1 = $('#'+box+'').find('.del-exam-id').val();
    var input2 = $('#'+box+'').find('.del-id').val();
    var input3 = $('#'+box+'').find('.del-table').val();
    var input4 = $('#'+box+'').find('.del-id-form').val();
    
        var values = {
                'examID': input1,
                'questionID': input2,
                'Info': input3,
                'idForm': input4
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: "edit-delete.inc.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: values,
            success: function(data)
            {
                $('.show-data').html(data);
                $('#'+box+'').remove();
                $('.countTQ').each(function(index) { $(this).find('h3').html('Question #'+(index+1)+''); });
                $('.audio-box').each(function(index) { $(this).find('h3').html('Audio #'+(index+1)+''); });
            }
        });

});
```

Comment: Appears from the `find()`s at the top that you might be repeating IDs in the page. You can't do that since an id is unique by definition. Use common classes instead

Comment: @charlietfl, thank you for letting me know. I've change them for classes. Still, the code does only work once. :(

Comment: Need more specific debugging details. Is the click handler only firing once? or does it fire and request is sending same data? Or request not being made? Or ...??

Comment: It was only firing once. I manage to solve it! Sorry for the trouble. I place the code inside $(document).ready(function(){}); and it started to work! I don't really understand why (I'm just starting to learn coding) but it did. Thank you for your help.